# Why does updating a variable containing `document.getElementById("text").value` not change the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here is my code, I want remove the `<textarea>`’s `value`.

```
<textarea name="text" id="text" cols="50" rows="6" placeholder="inset" required></textarea>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="등록">
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="추가">
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var date = document.querySelector("#date");
  var item = document.querySelector("#item");
  var sn = document.createElement("div");
  var sp = document.createElement("div");
  var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
  date.appendChild(sn);
  item.appendChild(sp);
  date.removeAttribute("id");
  item.removeAttribute("id");
  sn.setAttribute("id", "date");
  sp.setAttribute("id", "item");
  sn.append(today);
  sp.append(txt);
  txt = "";
});
```

When I write the code like above I can’t remove the value but in the one below it is working. Why is that?

```
var date = document.querySelector("#date");
  var item = document.querySelector("#item");
  var sn = document.createElement("div");
  var sp = document.createElement("div");
  var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
  date.appendChild(sn);
  item.appendChild(sp);
  date.removeAttribute("id");
  item.removeAttribute("id");
  sn.setAttribute("id", "date");
  sp.setAttribute("id", "item");
  sn.append(today);
  sp.append(txt);
  document.getElementById("text").value = "";
});
```

Comment: to remove the text of (id `text`) textarea `document.getElementById('text').value = ""`;

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = ""; // This changes the value of variable txt as ""
```

whereas,

```
document.getElementById("text").value = ""; // sets the value of element with id "text" to "".
```